# Why are browsers failing to load some static content?

Tags: admin, javascript, magento2.2.6, static-content-deploy

Using Magento 2.2.6.

I just installed a brand new install of 2.2.6 using Apache on OS X High Sierra, and with both Chrome and Firefox, after logging into the admin, the subnavigation does not work, and inspecting the page shows 12 js files have failed to load:

```
http://m226.local/pub/static/version1542310649/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
http://m226.local/pub/static/version1542310649/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/adminhtml/globals.js
```

etc.

There are 70 odd other js files that load just fine:

```
http://m226.local/pub/static/version1542310649/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js/theme.js
http://m226.local/pub/static/version1542310649/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap.js
```

etc.

When I curl the failed files, the file content comes back properly:

```
curl http://m226.local/pub/static/version1542310649/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/strings.js
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'underscore'
], function (_) {
    'use strict';

    var jsonRe = /^(?:\{[\w\W]*\}|\[[\w\W]*\])$/;

    return {

        /**
         * Attempts to convert string to one of the primitive values,
         * or to parse it as a valid json object.
         *
         * @param {String} str - String to be processed.
         * @returns {*}
         */
        castString: function (str) {
            try {
```

etc.

I've run `rm -rf var/cache/* pub/static/adminhtml/*` and `static:content:deploy` multiple times with no change.

Is there a reason these files are failing to load and if so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- open your magento database and run this query to remove version
  number from the path

  insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
- after this clear cache

  rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* 
  var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

Than deploy static content

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad - not sure what step in there made the difference, but I followed your instructions, and all the js in the back end loaded correctly - thx!